# Find a workaround for LO65830: GROUP CALENDAR TAB IS <UNTITLED> WHEN CREATED

Tags: calendar, lotus-notes

There is a bug in the Notes Client which has been documented since 2011:

LO65830: GROUP CALENDAR TAB IS  WHEN CREATED
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO65830

When you open a group calendar, the window title displays 'Group Calendar', then if you click on one of the persons listed in that group calendar, the window title changes to (Untitled) instead of chaning to the name of the Group Calendar. This becomes an issue when several Group calendars are open, because it's unclear in which Calendar one is.

As far as I can see this is a bug in the embedded scheduler, and I can't find any way to programatically change this with LotusScript.

I'm trying to deliver a workaround which could loop, for instance, through all open client windows, find out what should be the title, and change it accordingly. Or any other kind of workaround, in fact.

I know that it's a long shot, because the code is essentially out of our control as developers, but perhaps you might have a solution or an idea.

[image: Group Calendar]
This is the group calendar just after it's opened

[image]
This is what happens when you click one one of the persons in the group calendar

[image: design (GroupCalendar) form]
And if you look at the design of the (GroupCalendar) the formula it shows is exactly what should happen, but somehow that is getting overridden.

Comment: sound of tumbleweed....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there is a technical solution for this within the client.

One possibility would be to display the whole group calendar in a webapplication that retrieves and writes data back to the domino server using Domino Data Services.

Another workaround is to show all the group calendars in separate windows, as shown below:

[image]